# Fitting two table headings in one table and formatting it to look neat

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-5

I would like to use two different `<thead>`'s in the same table but i want them stacked nicely. The way it is now, the first heading has 1 less column then the 2nd one so it looks funky. If there is a way to expand that first heading out so that there isnt a space to the right of it, that would be great. Or maybe you know of a better way of tackling this problem. Here is how the table looks right now. [image] and here is the code that i am using to get this result

```
 <div class="hidden" id="part-req-section">
            <form method="post" name="partForm" id="partForm"> 
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <h3>Part Request</h3>
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">Part name*</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Quantity*</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Reason*</th><br>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="part-req-form-list">
                                            {{ part_request_formset.management_form }} 
                                            {% for some_form in part_request_formset %}
                                            <tr id="part-req-form" class="">
                                                <td>{{ some_form.part|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ some_form.quantity|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ some_form.reason|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                            <tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col">Aisle*</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Column*</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Shelf*</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Bin*</th>
                                                </tr>

                                            </thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{ location.aisle|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ location.column|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ location.shelf|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ location.bin|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                            </tr> 
                                            <tr id="empty-part-req-form" class="hidden">
                                                <td>{{ part_request_formset.empty_form.part|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ part_request_formset.empty_form.quantity|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ part_request_formset.empty_form.reason|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ location.aisle|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ location.column|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ location.shelf|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ location.bin|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="input-group-append float-end">
                                    <a href="" id="add-empty-part-form"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle text-success"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I tried making a 2nd table in this container but I dont think it will work the way i have my formset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there is a way to expand that first heading out so that there isnt a space to the right of it, that would be great.

[You can use the `colspan` attribute.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

`<th scope="col" colspan="2">`
`<td colspan="2">`